# Is there any limits for running multiple spiders with scrapy?

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I want to run many spiders with my scrapy. Does that make the crawling process slower or is there any limit for spiders to run? Is running many unlimited spiders makes the process slow ?

Is there anyone who is experienced with Scrapy?

Answer (score 1):

You can run multiple spiders concurrently and no, it will not make the process slower.

Comment: Assuming your spiders never become CPU-bound, i.e. network input/output (requests) remains slower than the Python code you use (to process those responses).